# Аренда виртуального сервера VPS/VDS

Tags: сервер, хостинг, vps, vds

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какой нибудь хостинг, размещающий свои сервера в России, у которого можно арендовать виртуальный сервер VPS/VDS с выделенным портом - ширина интернет канала больше 300 Мегабит / сек ? То есть скорость передачи данных должна быть стабильной, гарантированной от 300 Мбит/сек.